# jQuery UI sortable not working for dynamically-loaded content

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, dynamic, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable div that is loaded dynamically via `.load()`. Static sortable divs work fine, dynamic not so.

```
function dragAndDrop() {
    var sortBlock = $('.sortable');

    sortBlock.sortable({
        placeholder: 'ui-sortable-placeholder'
    });
}    

links.on('click', function() {
    ...
    sectionHolder.load(sortable-div);
    sortable();
});

<section id="sort">
    <ul class="sortable">
        <li class="product">1</li>
        <li class="product">2</li>
        <li class="product">3</li>
        <li class="product">4</li>
        <li class="product">5</li>
        <li class="product">6</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: `load()` is async, that's why. Call plugin initialization in `load()` complete callback. Just read the DOC

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`callback`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) here:

```
sectionHolder.load("sortable-div", function () {
    // Load is performed now.
    sortable();
});
```

Comment: @Ryan LoL. $h!7 happens.